# PHP form times out

Tags: php, forms, timeout

I have a php form. It has only 10 or so fields, but can take an hour or two to fill in.

However, the php page times out after 20 or so minutes, meaning you can spend time entering data into the fields, but if you haven't clicked submit, the form processes, does NOT insert the data into my mySQL database, and returns a blank form, leaving the user to re-enter ALL the data.

I've tried setting the `session.gc_maxlifetime`, javascript `setInterval` and `setTimeout`, and `.htaccess` solutions, all to no avail.

After 20 or so minutes: blank form.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean your session times out?  If that's the case, you could have an ajax method that pings your server every minute or so to ensure the process / session stays alive.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant session. And I've tried an ajax method as well every 3 minutes, but that didn't work either.

Comment: If you show us your code we might be able to find the problem, as Matthew points out the session could be kept alive with an simple ajax call now and then...

Comment: @DanShields The ajax ping page should contain `session_start()`.

Answer (score 0):

Php doesn't have forms.  HTML does.  HTML cannot "time out".  It sounds like it's the session that is timing out if anything